# Prevent Firefox from opening Privacy Notice when running web-ext?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

When developing web extensions, I test them with (for example) `web-ext run --bc -u https://stackoverflow.com/`.  With Firefox 56.0 (and `web-ext` 2.2.2), this:

1. opens a window "Browser Console",
2. opens another window and starts to load https://stackoverflow.com/ there, and
3. opens another tab in that window to display the [Firefox Privacy Notice](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/).

The last part is not only annoying in itself, but also distracting as (AFAICT) it fills the browser console with warnings related to that page's scripts.

How can I prevent Firefox from opening the Firefox Privacy Notice when called from `web-ext`, perhaps by setting some preference with `--pref`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext/issues/1114 you can use this:

```
web-ext run --pref='datareporting.policy.firstRunURL='
```